# SetInterval messages not changing

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I'm making a loading screen for a game I'm creating with html and JS.  I want various messages to display, about every three seconds.  The SetInterval function doesn't seem to be rotating the messages, even though it works with something else (like an alert every three seconds).  here's the code I've written for the changing messages.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>Loading screen</title></head>
<script>
let messageNum = 1;

setInterval(function(){ 
  messageNum++
 }, 1000);

if (messageNum >3) {
  messageNum = 1;
}

if (messageNum === 1) {
  document.write('Message number ONE');
}

if (messageNum === 2) {
  document.write('Message number TWO');
}

if (messageNum === 3) {
  document.write('Message number THREE');
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: put your ifs inside the setInterval, they run on the stack only once.

Answer (score 3):

try to execute your code inside the setInterval-function:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>Loading screen</title></head>
<script>
let messageNum = 1;

setInterval(function(){ 
  messageNum++
  if (messageNum >3) {
    messageNum = 1;
  }

  if (messageNum === 1) {
    document.write('Message number ONE');
  }

  if (messageNum === 2) {
    document.write('Message number TWO');
  }

  if (messageNum === 3) {
    document.write('Message number THREE');
  }
 }, 1000);


</script>
</html>
```

Regards

Comment: but you should not execute document.wrote inside a script-tag... think about your app-design.. try to use id´s or something to inject the messages you want to write to an element in the body...

Answer (score 1):

setInterval is an asynchronous operation, so your events happen in the wrong order.

You need to run your output logic WHEN the number changes. Right now, you are running all your output logic before the first time the setInterval runs even the first time.

```js
let messageNum = 1;

setInterval(function(){ 
  outputNum();
  messageNum++;
}, 1000);

function outputNum() {
  if (messageNum > 3) {
    messageNum = 1;
  }

  if (messageNum === 1) {
    document.write('Message number ONE<br />');
  }

  if (messageNum === 2) {
    document.write('Message number TWO<br />');
  }

  if (messageNum === 3) {
    document.write('Message number THREE<br />');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>Loading screen</title></head>
<script>
let messageNum = 1;

const interval = setInterval(function(){ 
  messageNum++;
  if (messageNum >3) {
  messageNum = 1;
}

if (messageNum === 1) {
  document.write('Message number ONE');
}

if (messageNum === 2) {
  document.write('Message number TWO');
}

if (messageNum === 3) {
  document.write('Message number THREE');
}
 }, 1000);


</script>
</html>
```

Also make sure to clear the interval when needed. It might cause memory leaks. you can clear interval using this code:

```
clearInterval(interval)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to stop your timer at 3 hence the following.

You can make it better by introducing a function which returns the wanted message and then concatenate it to the default message

```
let messageNum = 0;
const id = setInterval(function() {
  messageNum++;
  document.write("Message " + writeMessage(messageNum));
  // stop the timer
  if (messageNum === 3) clearInterval(id);
}, 1000);

function writeMessage(num) {
  switch (num) {
    case 1:
      return "ONE";

    case 2:
      return "TWO";

    case 3:
      return "THREE";

    default:
      return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` will run the function I'm your first argument every `x` ms (second argument).

Since your function only increment the variable, you won't see the message.

The message printing and `if` statements are not part of that function that run inside the `setInterval` which make those lines to run only once.

You need to put the 'if' statements and message printing inside the function triggered in `setInterval`.

**P.S.**

Please make sure you are using `document.write` only for testing or streaming. It is not a good practice to use it inside a function, since it will overwrite the existing HTML each time `write` is called.

Answer (score 0):

With the current code, setInterval would still be working. i.e., `messageNum++` will keep on incrementing, however, you're not capturing any feedback or output from there, . That's why when you add an alert you'll see that the messageNum would have increased with each alert. (try `console.log(messageNum)`, it would work too.)

If your aim is to keep incrementing the messageNum with setInterval, and show different message based on the current value of the `messageNum`, you will have to check the conditions inside the setInterval.

setInterval will have to do the following things together.
1. increment the variable
2. check the variable's current value and show a message.

```
let messageNum = 1;

setInterval(() => {
 if (messageNum > 3) {
  messageNum = 1;
 }

 if (messageNum === 1) {
  document.write('Message number ONE');
 } else if (messageNum === 2) {
  document.write('Message number TWO');
 } else {
  document.write('Message number THREE');
 }
}, 1000)
```

**NOTE:**

Use **if-else condition effectively** so that, **once one condition is satisfied, the other conditions will not be needlessly checked**.

In its current form, even if the messageNum === 1 is satisfied, the program will check the remaining 2 `if` conditions (messageNum === 2, messageNum === 3) unnecessarily.